# The position of the net in table tennis

Tags: rules, equipment, table-tennis

Are there any rules indicating how the net should be placed in table tennis?

- Should it touch the top?
- Should it touch the table?

I'm not totally sure. It always seems that we just put it in the middle of the metal holder (not sure what they are called) on both sides.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Regulations](http://www.ittf.com/ittf_handbook/ittf_hb.html) state the following (excerpt):

> 2.02   THE NET ASSEMBLY
> 2.02.01     The net assembly shall consist of the net, its suspension and the supporting posts, including the clamps attaching them to the table.
> 2.02.02     The net shall be suspended by a cord attached at each end to an upright post 15.25cm high, the outside limits of the post being 15.25cm outside the side line.
> 2.02.03     The top of the net, along its whole length, shall be 15.25cm above the playing surface.
> 2.02.04     The bottom of the net, along its whole length, shall be as close as possible to the playing surface and the ends of the net shall be as close as possible to the supporting posts.

Type *net* in the keyword search to get the full list but the ones above are linked to its placement.

Comment: Which rules do you normally follow usattc? or ittc? or are both the same?

Answer (score 2):

Some other things to keep in mind about the net are

1. Tightness of the net - the looser it is, the more shots that hit the top of the net will roll over to the other side. The tighter it is, the more shots will bounce back and not go over the net.
2. Not all shots are required to go over the net. Watch the end of this point: http://youtu.be/858kpMv7hDQ?t=2m